# Any way to remove the last check in my converter?

Tags: python

For an interview question I made a roman to integer converter:

```
def romanToInt(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        mapping = {"I": 1, "V":5, "X":10, "L":50, "C":100, "D":500, "M":1000}
        numeral_list = list(s)

        num_list = [[mapping[i], -1] for i in numeral_list]
        count = 0
        i = 0
        while(i < len(num_list) - 1):
            if num_list[i] < num_list[i + 1]:
                count += num_list[i + 1][0] - num_list[i][0]
                num_list[i+1][1] = 1
                num_list[i][1] = 1
                i += 2
            else:
                count += num_list[i][0]
                num_list[i][1] = 1
                i += 1
        if num_list[-1][1] == -1:
            count += num_list[-1][0]
        return count
```

As you can see I sometimes miss the last digit because I didn't want to get an index error. To avoid that I added an extra attribute that would check if the last element was checked or not (in cases where s[len(s)-2] < s[len(s)-1], s[len(s)-1] is checked, but if s[len(s)-2] > s[len(s)-1] then s[len(s)-1] is not checked.

Having an extra check and using extra space just for one element is highly erroneous. Where am I going wrong in my logic?

EDIT: Here was my code before

```
def romanToInt(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        mapping = {"I": 1, "V":5, "X":10, "L":50, "C":100, "D":500, "M":1000}
        numeral_list = list(s)

        num_list = [mapping[i] for i in numeral_list]
        count = 0
        i = 0
        while(i < len(num_list)-1):
            if num_list[i] < num_list[i + 1]:
                count += num_list[i + 1] - num_list[i]
                i += 2
            else:
                count += num_list[i]
                i += 1
        return count
```

It failed on several test cases since it did not count the last digit

Comment: Can you give an input where that would happen? You have problems, but I think this will generate the correct output for any properly formed roman numeral with those characters.

Comment: it is correct, but looks bad. my question is how to get rid of the last check. unfortunately i don't have test cases on me as i ran it through a site that had test cases on it, but for example if a string ended in "IX" it would be computed correctly but "XI" would not. any string where `s[-2] < s[-1]` would fail

Comment: It works for XI and IX

Comment: Wait, you don't have test cases, but you just said XI and IX.  I know you're at a computer. print romanToInt('IX')

Comment: You're right, but for sure it failed on certain cases. Unfortunately the site doesn't show me which test cases it ran so I'm not sure, but when I first saw an error and saw my output I saw it wasn't including the final digit. This is inherently because of my loop, so I was asking whether my logic was wrong. Obviously not every code uses tuples to verify if the final result was checked or not, so i'm wondering what is wrong with my logic.

Comment: I googled "python roman numeral", found a simple script at http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docutils/utils/roman.py and tested your code against all valid roman numerals computed from range(1,2000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they are looking for before anything else is whether your code is easily readable and maintainable. That's more important than being right, in my opinion, although the interviewer may disagree -- so make it also correct.

Check for invalid inputs. What if they give a string like 'VXQIII'? Do you want to enforce any rules or are you okay with giving 'VVVVV' = 25?

Throw in a unit test or test function for bonus points.

You invent a complicated structure with mysterious code numbers instead of using a clearly named variable like 'has_been_counted'. This makes your code hard to read. Therefore all your code will be hard for other programmers to read and maintain. And when I say other programmers, I mean you, next week, when you can't remember why you did that.

Additionally, that seen flag is unnecessary. You already have an array index telling you what you have and have not seen.

Python specific:

For an interview use pep-8. You can figure out how strict they are about style later, but python people can be pickier about that than most languages.

Self is unused, and it's not shown as being a class member anyway. "print romanToInt('XCIV')" will raise an error.

Speaking of errors, Python people may appreciate catching invalid characters with a try..except around the mapping lookup, and then reraise as ValueError('Not a valid roman numeral'). Maybe a python person can comment on what exception type to use for that, but I think ValueError is the right one.

converting s to a list of characters is unnecessary.  You can already iterate a string as a list of characters.

```
for letter in 'XCIV':
    print letter

X
C
I
V
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed comment. you're totally right about my loop, but how should i circumvent that? how should i rewrite my loop to ensure i'm checking every digit but also check whether the next number is greater than the current number?

Comment: I missed something on the loop.  You loop until the penultimate element, specifically because you want the last element to be a special case (can't check next).  There's nothing wrong with that. It might warrant a comment in the code is all.  And I still think it's correct for good inputs, but that's why we test. :)